# Sort by date ascending with nulls last

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I use java and hibernate 3.2.5.ga  .

I have a table with a date column. I want to create a hql query that will sort the result by date ascending but will put the nulls last.

Normally I the sort by date asc returns nulls first and the "NULL LAST" keyword does not work.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Will a SQL solution be enough? If that is the case, what is the DBMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use query like this:

```
SELECT YourDateColumn
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourCondition
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN YourDateColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  YourDateColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround solution , may not be the right way , but you can think of having an extra column "temp" in your database and define a trigger which will update the temp value everytime there is an update to the date column and in that trigger , if the date is NULL , set temp value to 100 and if it is not set temp value to 0 .

Now in your query do a sort by temp asc, date asc , by which all the NOT null dates will come first followed by dates which are NULL

PS: I haven't tried it myself ,so just give it a try

Comment: it will work, but very unelegant to change the schema just so I can sort

Comment: Completely agreed , or you can try setting the date to some default value if its NULL and then try to do a sort.